# Is it Possible to Make Composer 2 work with PHP 7.4.33

Tags: composer-php, php-7.4

I'm trying to get my PHP website app setup to use Cloudinary for image file storage.

On my local machine, I am running `PHP Version 8.1.2`.  My website is on a shared-hosting site and is using `PHP Version: 7.4.33`.  I've installed `composer version 2.6.6`.

On the hosting server, I cannot update the PHP version higher than `7.4.33` atm.

When I try to upload a file to `cloudinary` I get an error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 7.4.33.
```

The error is pointing to: `/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24, but is triggered by line 7, I believe`:

```
7 if (!(PHP_VERSION_ID >= 80100)) {
8    $issues[] = 'Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running ' . PHP_VERSION . '.';
9 }
```

I tried fudging the `PHP_VERSION_ID` to `70400`, but that just lead to more errors in another file.

I tried downgrading my version of composer, but that did not help. Maybe the setup for composer 1 is different.

Is there a way to make `composer` work with PHP 7.4?

Comment: If you are baking a cake, and you have no sugar, would you expect simply changing the label on the salt recipient to make the trick, and that the cake would be alright?

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged this for composer but didn't tag for the package that's failing.  By their documentation, composer works in general for PHP > 7.2.5 and from your error is working as intended.

Comment: Looks like your own composer.json contains such a requirement. Can you share it? Also, any production environment that cannot be upgraded to a supported version of PHP should be replaced by a more current one

Comment: Finally, why do you use PHP 8.1 during development when your production system is way older? Wouldn't it be better to use the **same** version, to avoid that you write code that isn't compatble?

Comment: @NicoHaase  Thank you for your comment. It prompted me to engage the hosting provider.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the hosting service to update php to 8.1.2. it works now.